# expect script + write "if"  in expect script

Tags: solaris, shell-scripting, ksh, expect

please advice what's wrong with my exepct syntax ( I run expect in ksh script on Solaris 10 machine )

I want to verify if OS is linux

so if it true the expect check if prompt is "#" or ">"

and then run the "ls" command

but I get the error below
please advice what could be the problem

```
     OS=solaris

     expect_do_something=`cat << EOF
     set timeout -1
     spawn   telnet 0 $IP_ADDRESS
     expect login:           {send $LOGIN\r}
     expect Password:        {send "$PASS\r"}




 if { "$OS" == "solaris" }
    {
      expect -re {#|>}        {send ls\r}
    }

 expect eof
 EOF`

 expect -c  "$expect_do_something"
```

the error from expect:

```
  wrong # args: no script following " "solaris" == "solaris" " argument
     while executing
  "if { "solaris" == "solaris" }"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expect, being an extension of Tcl, has to respect Tcl's [very few syntax rules](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/Tcl.htm). In Tcl, a newline signifies the end of the command (see [this rule](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M5)), so you **must** put the open brace of the if-body on the same line.

```
if { "$OS" == "solaris" } {
  # ......................^
  expect -re {#|>} {send ls\r}
}
```